# Arduino Program Stop Working after 1 sec

Tags: c++, arduino

I have a program that is supposed to turn on 4 LEDs simultaneously in 4 steps:

1. the 4 LEDs are turned on for 500 ms using PMW for a value of 10mv.
2. the 4 LEDs are turned on for 500 ms using PMW for a value of 250mv.
3. the 4 LEDs are turned on for 500 ms using PMW for a value of 50mv.
4. the 4 LEDs are turned on for 500 ms using PMW for a value of 0mv.

The program makes the stpe 1 and 2 and then it stops wotking and the LEDs keep on at 250mv.

I tried to change the duration for the first two steps but it always stops after these first two steps are done and don't continue the 3 and 4.

I used oriented object programming so please be patient with the code; actually the most important classes are Effect and Motor.

Node.cpp: this class creates a Node which is defined by an amplitude and a duration for the selected for example: amplitude: 10mv duration:500ms

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "Node.h"

Node::Node(){}
Node::~Node(){}

int Node::getAmplitude()
    {
    return  _amplitude;
    }

unsigned long Node::getDuration()
    {
    return  _duration;
    }

void Node::setPatternNode(int amplitude,unsigned long duration)
    {
    _amplitude=amplitude;
    _duration=duration;
    }
```

Pattern.cpp : 
this class creates an array of Nodes created initially to result in a particular pattern of vibration for example: amplitude{10,250,50,0} duration{500,500,500,500}

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "Pattern.h"
#include "Node.h"
#include "QueueArray.h"
#include "Motor.h"

Pattern::Pattern(){}
Pattern::~Pattern(){}

QueueArray <Node> Pattern::setPattern(int amplitude[4],unsigned long duration[4]){
    QueueArray <Node> queue;
    unsigned long nodeDurationSum = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<4;i++){
    Node node;
    nodeDurationSum = nodeDurationSum + duration[i]; //the reference for duration calculation is patternStartTime 
    node.setPatternNode(amplitude[i],nodeDurationSum);
    queue.enqueue(node);
    }
    return queue;
}
```

Motor.cpp: this class affects the pattern(s) created by the class Pattern to the selected motor(s).

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "Motor.h"
#include "QueueArray.h"
#include "Node.h"
#include "Pattern.h"


Motor::Motor()
    {
    }

Motor::Motor(int pin)
    {
        pinMode(pin, OUTPUT);
        _pin = pin;
    }

Motor::~Motor()
    {
    }


    void Motor::runMotor()
    {
        if(_isMotorActive){
        _currentTime=millis();//_currentTime is declared as "unsigned long"
        Serial.println(_currentTime);       
        if(_currentTime < _currentNode.getDuration())
            {
            analogWrite(_pin,_currentNode.getAmplitude());
            } 
        else 
            {
            if(_currentPattern.isEmpty())
               {
                _isMotorActive = false;
               }
             updateCurrentNode();
            }

        }

    }


    void Motor::motorSetPattern(QueueArray <Node> p)
    {
    _currentPattern = p;
    _isMotorActive = true;
    _patternStartTime = millis();//_patternStartTime is declared as "unsigned long"
    updateCurrentNode();
    }

int Motor::getCurrentPatternLength()
    {
    return _currentPattern.count();
    }


void Motor::updateCurrentNode()
    {
    _currentNode = _currentPattern.dequeue();
    }
```

Effect.cpp: this class run more than 1 motor, each motor is run following the Pattern to whom it is affected.

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "Effect.h"
#include "Motor.h"

Effect::Effect(){}

Effect::Effect(Motor m1,Motor m2,Motor m3,Motor m4,QueueArray <Node> p1,QueueArray <Node> p2,QueueArray <Node> p3,QueueArray <Node> p4)
    {
    _vibmotor1=m1;
    _vibmotor2=m2;
    _vibmotor3=m3;
    _vibmotor4=m4;

    _motorPattern1 = p1;
    _motorPattern2 = p2;
    _motorPattern3 = p3;
    _motorPattern4 = p4;

    _vibmotor1.motorSetPattern(_motorPattern1);
    _vibmotor2.motorSetPattern(_motorPattern2);
    _vibmotor3.motorSetPattern(_motorPattern3);
    _vibmotor4.motorSetPattern(_motorPattern4);
    }

Effect::~Effect()
    {
    }


void Effect::runEffect()
    {
    _vibmotor1.runMotor();
    _vibmotor2.runMotor();      
    _vibmotor3.runMotor();      
    _vibmotor4.runMotor();      
    }
```

And this is the arduino sketch:

```
#include <Effect.h>
#include <Motor.h>
#include <Node.h>
#include <Pattern.h>
#include <QueueArray.h>

Motor vibmotor1(3);
Motor vibmotor2(5);
Motor vibmotor3(6);
Motor vibmotor4(9);

Pattern pattern;

int amplitude1[4] = {10,250,50,0};
unsigned long duration1[4] = {500,500,500,500};
int amplitude2[4] = {10,250,50,0};
unsigned long duration2[4] = {500,500,500,500};
int amplitude3[4] = {10,250,50,0};
unsigned long duration3[4] = {500,500,500,500};
int amplitude4[4] = {10,250,50,0};
unsigned long duration4[4] = {500,500,500,500};

QueueArray <Node> p1 = pattern.setPattern(amplitude1,duration1);
QueueArray <Node> p2 = pattern.setPattern(amplitude2,duration2);
QueueArray <Node> p3 = pattern.setPattern(amplitude3,duration3);
QueueArray <Node> p4 = pattern.setPattern(amplitude4,duration4);

Effect effect1(vibmotor1,vibmotor2,vibmotor3,vibmotor4,p1,p2,p3,p4);

void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(9600);
}  


void loop()
 {
   effect1.runEffect(); 

 }
```

Comment: Just one remark. Arduino is not a PC, so please try avoid using it like if it has tons of GB of memory and MIPS.
Do you really need QueueArrays? do you have to dynamically change the number of elements? Or you can change it to a plain old vector of four elements?
And if you have a "dynamic" number of elements, can you tell a reasonable maximum value (e.g. 10) and then use an array instead of a dynamic queue?
Arduino has low resources... Don't waste them.. ;)

Answer (score 3):

In your `void Motor::run()`
you are filling your `_currentTime` with `millis()`
But it is giving you the time since the arduino started and NOT since the `Effect::runEffect()` started. So it could be already higher than the duration of your first effect.
Try to store the actual starting time when you first call `runEffect()` and use it as an offset for your `_currentTime`

For example in your `runMotor()`

```
void Motor::runMotor()
{
       if(_firstRun == true)
       {
           _startTime = millis();
           _firstRun = false;
       }

       ...your code...

       _currentTime = millis() - _startTime;

       ...your code...
}
```

That is just what i noticed. Try it that first. If i does not help come back and say so.

Comment: thanks for your help. I tried that, the program works for slightly more time than before but still stops just after the 2nd step. I put serial prints in order to make it easy for you cuz you'll see diretly the data and can get a clear idea but i don't know how to put this in the comment. what can i do?

Comment: ok. you find in the link the runMoror code with serial prints and the result i got in serial monitor [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25033739/aruino-program-doesnt-work-after-1sec?noredirect=1#comment38933770_25033739)

Comment: have you seen the result? please i really need your help

Comment: delete the _firstRun=true after updateNodes()

Comment: actually it was initially without _firstRun=true after updateNodes() but it stops even earlier that's why i tried to add it but still not working properly. your remark precise the exact problem which is for sure in the time manipulation, are there any other possible solutions?

Comment: set it true initially. e.g. in the motorSetPattern() where you set _isMotorActive to true

Comment: yes that's what I have done @John since the beginning

Comment: @YacineBougrinat upload your complete project as you are using it right now on a repo and ill have a look.

Comment: Thanks @JohnDoe you can download the complete project from this link [link](http://www.filedropper.com/vibmotorproject)

Comment: did you get the project?